# Defining fittype object from custom function

Tags: matlab, function

I'm trying to define a `fittype` object from the function (written in a separate .m file)

```
y = fun(x,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,P),
```

where `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`, `c5`, `c6` are the variable fitting parameters and `P` is a constant struct:

```
ft = fittype(@(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,x) fun(x,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,P), 'independent', {'x'}, 'dependent', {'y'});
```

but get the following errors:

```
Error using fittype>iTestCustomModelEvaluation (line 730)
Custom equations must produce an output vector, matrix, or array that is the same size and shape as the input data.
This custom equation fails to meet that requirement:

Error in fittype>iCreateFittype (line 367)
    iTestCustomModelEvaluation( obj );

Error in fittype (line 324)
                obj = iCreateFittype( obj, varargin{:} );
```

The function works fine producing same size `x` & `y` data so I have no clue why defining the fittype fails.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help without seeing the internals of `fun` (or an example that demonstrates the same issue).

Comment: Silly question, but does it say the same thing if you add `'x'/'y'` as a string and not a cell? And are you *absolutely* sure that `fun` returns the same shape as the input `x`, regardless of its dimensions? Also, I'd try adding `P` as a problem-dependent parameter, but again, I'd be surprised if that helped.

Comment: What about transposing the data columns to rows or vice versa? fit() can be funny about that.

Answer (score 0):

Struct P was not needed to be added as a problem-dependent parameter. What fixed the problem was making sure that my input/output vectors where columns of the same size. Fit() works only with columns. I know it now! Thanks for your suggestions.